# How can I justify without making a new line in mdframed?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mdframed

```
 \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green]     
 \textbf{Theorem:}     
 \begin{center} A set $E$ is {\bf open} $\iff E^c$ is {\bf closed} \end{center}      
 \centerline{or equivalently,} 
 \centerline{A set $E$ is {\bf open} $\iff E^c$ is {\bf closed} }
\end{mdframed}
```

So basically I want to get `Theorem` to align on the same line as `\begin{center} A set $E$ is {\bf open} $\iff E^c$ is {\bf closed} \end{center}` without producing another new line. Adding `flushleft` inside the center environment has no effect.

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: you can easily use `minipage` inside `mdframed` environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using *only* `center` and then some box-control (via `\phantom`) for the first line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,mdframed}
\begin{document}
% Original layout/use
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green]
  \textbf{Theorem:}
  \begin{center} A set $E$ is {\bf open} $\iff E^c$ is {\bf closed} \end{center}
  \centerline{or equivalently,}
  \centerline{A set $E$ is {\bf open} $\iff E^c$ is {\bf closed} }
\end{mdframed}

\bigskip

% Updated layout/use
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=green]
\begin{center}
  \textbf{Theorem:} \hfill A set~$E$ is \textbf{open} $\iff E^c$ is \textbf{closed} \hfill \phantom{\textbf{Theorem:}} \\
  or equivalently, \\
  A set~$E$ is \textbf{open} $\iff E^c$ is \textbf{closed}
\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

The first line is set at full width using a displayed **Theorem:** on the left, and a `\phantom` **Theorem:** on the right.

Comment: Say I want to make some space in between each line (vertical space), how would I accomplish this? seperating the centers and adding \\ didn't work

Comment: @jak: Use `\\[<len>]` where you specify `<len>`. For example, `\\[\jot]` inserts a `3pt` gap, `\\[\baselineskip]` inserts a empty line.